# How to create a Torus with a non-circular cross section?

Tags: modeling

I want to create a torus-like shape, however using a cross section that is not circular. In particular, the shape I'm trying to make would have a cross section that consists of a rectangle, with one side replace by a half-circle (as in the picture). The circular side would be inwards, towards the center of the Torus. [image]

I have found answers for how to do this out there, but all of those that I've found apply only to pre-2.8 Blender.

Comment: you can create a torus, delete its inner side and extrude inwards, or use the spin tool

Comment: Nothing is changed much, some of the tools just moved to a different place in the interface, but the workflow should be the same. Please indicate which links you've looked at.

Answer (score 4):

You've already made the profile, you're nearly there..

In Edit mode, drag the profile a little way from its object's origin

[image]

(Here, the axis of rotation is going to be Y, it's the profile's Y axis, as well as the world's)

Give the profile a *Screw* modifier..

[image]

Comment: Love it!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create it with a **beveled curve**:

- remove the face from your "D" shape, and convert the object to a **Curve**
- add a Bezier Circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, Curve → Circle)
- in the Object Data Properties of the circle, set the shape object as **Bevel** object

If you like, add a Bevel modifier so the edge looks nicer when it's shaded smooth, and convert it back to a mesh.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [F2](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/f2.html#f2) addon.

- Delete the outer face of a torus by selecting the equator edge loop with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> and then growing the selection with <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Num +</kbd>
- Select two adjacent vertices, press <kbd>F</kbd> to connect
- Hold <kbd>F</kbd> to fill
- <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> to add an edge loop if desired

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Same as [@Timaroberts' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/209746/92768), delete the outer faces.

Select the top and bottom edge loops.

And do ***Bridge Edge Loops***

[image]